# Following symbolic link in Grails 3

Tags: grails, grails-3.1

In Grails 2.x, to allow following symbolic links, we can add following in the `scripts/_Events.groovy`:

```
eventConfigureTomcat = { tomcat ->
    def ctx = tomcat.host.findChild("")
    ctx.allowLinking = true     // Follow soft links
}
```

How can we achieve the same in Grails 3? I've tried creating the same script file in `src/main/scripts` directory in Grails 3 but didn't help.

**Edit:**

I also tried adding following line in `Bootstrap.groovy`:

```
Holders.getServletContext().allowLinking = true
```

[GitHub issue #10045](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10045)

Comment: The servlet context is passed into `BootStrap.init{}` as an argument.  Is that too late to accomplish what you need?

Comment: No @JeffScottBrown that didn't work. It is too late to configure tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've figured out the solution for following symbolic link in Grails 3 with the help of examples provided by [graemerocher](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10045#issuecomment-235714810).

You just need to add the following to your `./grails-app/init/<package>/Application.groovy`:

```
@Bean
EmbeddedServletContainerFactory containerFactory() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory containerFactory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory()

    containerFactory.addContextCustomizers(new TomcatContextCustomizer() {
        @Override
        void customize(Context context) {
            StandardRoot root = new StandardRoot(context)
            root.setAllowLinking(true)
            context.setResources(root)
        }
    });

    return containerFactory
}
```

Packages to import:

```
import org.apache.catalina.Context
import org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerFactory
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatContextCustomizer
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
```

Comment: Source: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10045#issuecomment-235896128