# how to access file in root server with spring security

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, grails

i am using grails 3.1.1
i already deployment my war file with tomcat 8 and i store all my image's file into `/app/Item/`

this is my folder's structure in my server.

```
/app/Item/<all my image>
/home
/root/apache-tomcat-8/
     /apache-tomcat-8/webapps
     /apache-tomcat-8/webapps/ROOT.war
     /apache-tomcat-8/bin
     /apache-tomcat-8/logs
     /apache-tomcat-8/work
     /apache-tomcat-8/temp
     /apache-tomcat-8/conf
```

now i am using `symlink` to access `/app/Item`
so i create a symlink in `/apache-tomcat-8/webapps/images` with name `images`
so when i access `localhost:8080/images/100.JPG` it will access to `/app/Item/100.JPG`

but i will get some error log if i rerun my tomcat, because folder `images` where i create with `symlink` isnot in my grails project.
like this..

```
28-Feb-2017 12:43:44.962 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup Unexpected exception resolving reference
 java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver from ClassLoader:java.net.URLClassLoader@1fb3ebeb;ClassLoader:ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: gambarku
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@1fb3ebeb

    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:283)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:718)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:650)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:468)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:143)
```

### now i want to know how to access my folder `/app/Item/` without `symlink` but from my grails application?

i tried to deploy without `symlink` or `images`'s folder (shortcut)

```
    [root@li1447-147 bin]# cd ..
[root@li1447-147 apache-tomcat-8.5.8]# cd we
-bash: cd: we: No such file or directory
[root@li1447-147 apache-tomcat-8.5.8]# cd webapps/
[root@li1447-147 webapps]# rm -rf *
[root@li1447-147 webapps]# clear
[root@li1447-147 webapps]# cd ..
[root@li1447-147 apache-tomcat-8.5.8]# cd bin/
[root@li1447-147 bin]# ./startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /root/apache-tomcat-8.5.8
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /root/apache-tomcat-8.5.8
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /root/apache-tomcat-8.5.8/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_112
Using CLASSPATH:       /root/apache-tomcat-8.5.8/bin/bootstrap.jar:/root/apache-    tomcat-8.5.8/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
[root@li1447-147 bin]# tail -f ../logs/catalina.out
28-Feb-2017 16:13:06.353 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Ini    tializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
28-Feb-2017 16:13:06.368 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.    getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
28-Feb-2017 16:13:06.370 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Ini    tializing ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-443"]
28-Feb-2017 16:13:06.613 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.    getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
28-Feb-2017 16:13:06.613 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Ini    tializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
28-Feb-2017 16:13:06.615 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.    getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
28-Feb-2017 16:13:06.615 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load I    nitialization processed in 796 ms
28-Feb-2017 16:13:06.637 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.st    artInternal Starting service Catalina
28-Feb-2017 16:13:06.637 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.sta    rtInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.8
28-Feb-2017 16:13:06.657 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu    p.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /root/apache-tomcat-8.5    .8/webapps/ROOT.war
28-Feb-2017 16:13:13.193 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.    TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs.     Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scan    ned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can i    mprove startup time and JSP compilation time.

Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core

28-Feb-2017 16:13:49.628 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu    p.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /root/apache-tomcat    -8.5.8/webapps/ROOT.war has finished in 42,968 ms
28-Feb-2017 16:13:49.632 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start St    arting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-80]
28-Feb-2017 16:13:49.638 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start St    arting ProtocolHandler [https-jsse-nio-443]
28-Feb-2017 16:13:49.639 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start St    arting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
28-Feb-2017 16:13:49.640 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start     Server startup in 43024 ms
```

------------------this is for `symlink`

then i tried to [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812244/simplest-way-to-serve-static-data-from-outside-the-application-server-in-a-java) and add this code to my `server.xml`

`<Context docBase="/app/Item" path="/gambarku" />`

then startup.sh again.

i get this log.

```
28-Feb-2017 17:00:49.701 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource Failed to register in JMX: javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to load class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver from ClassLoader:java.net.URLClassLoader@1fb3ebeb;ClassLoader:ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: gambarku
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@1fb3ebeb

28-Feb-2017 17:00:49.772 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /root/apache-tomcat-8.5.8/webapps/ROOT.war
28-Feb-2017 17:00:56.238 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
```

**this log is same when i tried to use `symlink`.**

i tried to find some documentation and i already check in folder `WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.20.jar` and build.gradle with `runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.20'`

[image]

[image]

Comment: The error is related a DB-Driver, not filesystem access!

Comment: @Jens yes, when running up my ROOT.war , the application will automatic create table base on my `domain-class`, that eror because, i don't have `domain-class` with name `images`

Comment: No the error is because the application can not load the Mysql- Driver: `Unable to load class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver from ClassLoader:java`

Comment: @Jens really? that erorr not show aftar i delete the `image`'s symlink :(

Comment: so you can restart tomcat without any issues after you delete the image folder? Can you try deploying/restart without adding the symlink or the image folder?

Comment: @artemisian see my update question, i just try it.

Comment: when i receive this log `Unable to load class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver from ClassLoader:java`, my application still running and i can access from my domain/ip address

Comment: Please check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38268498/following-symbolic-link-in-grails-3

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812244/simplest-way-to-serve-static-data-from-outside-the-application-server-in-a-java  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417658/how-to-config-tomcat-to-serve-images-from-an-external-folder-outside-webapps and alternatively http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html

Comment: @vahid i tried your suggestion link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812244/simplest-way-to-serve-static-data-from-outside-the-application-server-in-a-java

Comment: @artemisian see my update question

Comment: check my answer, hopefully it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
def image = new File('/app/Item/image1.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot but might solve your issue, it's very similar to the config you had originally, just adding **allowLinking="true"**:

- Create a symlink between **/app/Item** and **/apache-tomcat-8/webapps/images**
- Add this to your configuration

  ```
        <Context docBase="/app/Item" path="/images" allowLinking="true"/>
  ```

Comment: i must create symlink again?

Comment: i still get the same log..
01-Mar-2017 03:31:55.091 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource Failed to register in JMX: javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to load class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver from ClassLoader:java.net.URLClassLoader@1fb3ebeb;ClassLoader:ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: gambarku
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@1fb3ebeb

Comment: Why it says gambarku, shouldn't say image?

Comment: yes, i am change folder name so like this `Context docBase="/app/Item" path="/gambarku" allowLinking="true"/>`

Comment: Can you change it to image? Does the image folder exists in your webapps folder in your grails project?

Comment: wait, must the `image`'s folder exist in webapps?

Comment: Doesn't hurt to add it.

Comment: in `ROOT`'s folder or `webapps`?

Comment: In the webapps folder of your project. Not the ROOT

Comment: No, not like that. In the webapp folder of the project source code. Then you need to create the war file again

Comment: there's no `webapps` folder in my project, i am using grails, maybe you mean folder `assets` ?

Comment: Right assets is Grails 3 :)

Comment: i already create folder `image` in folder assets then build war again..but i am thinking that i access file in `assets`'s folder with `localhost:8080/projectname/assets/100.JPG` but if i am setting `allowlinking` from `image` to `/app/Item` then  what is the url of `/app/Item`?

Comment: when i create a blank's folder in `assets` and create a war file again, the grails will remove that's blank folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136918/discussion-between-artemisian-and-akiong).

Comment: let's go to the chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136918/discussion-between-artemisian-and-akiong